# Jquery Make Array Key To Be Var

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

What I'm trying to do its add array on my function and the key to be var key, example I send this to my function:

```
 var obj = {
  "div_id":"#Menu_Videos",
  "div_class":".wideDropdown_Menu_Videos",
 };
 wideDropdown(obj);
```

and my function is

```
 function wideDropdown(obj) {
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
   var key = value;
  });
 }
```

but its not working how I can make the key on my function to be example

```
 var div_id = "#Menu_Videos",
```

**Update**

I need something like this command to i can include on my function

```
var obj[key] = obj[value];
```

Comment: so basically you want to create variables dynamically based on an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), although in general using eval is a bad idea.

```
$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    eval(key + '=' + '"' + value + '"');
});
```

According to MDN:

> The argument of the eval() function is a string. If the string represents an expression, eval() evaluates the expression. If the argument represents one or more JavaScript statements, eval() performs the statements. Do not call eval() to evaluate an arithmetic expression; JavaScript evaluates arithmetic expressions automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do:

```
var div_id = obj[key];
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6LPCJ/

Comment: var div_id its obj[key] and "#Menu_Videos" its obj[value] .. so i need something like var obj[key] = obj[value];

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're searching for is 'extract'.

This function does the Magic:
http://phpjs.org/functions/extract/